# Hive ORC or AVRO format with field delimiters

Tags: hive, delimiter, hiveql, orc

What does it mean for a hive table with ORC or Avro format to have the Field delimiter specified? Does hive ignore even if its specified?

For example,

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists T (
C1    STRING ,
C2    STRING )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001' 
STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a compress format, its used. The delimiter need not be specified.